# How to configure Sublime Text 3 editor settings for specific file extensions?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to change some editor settings that's only applicable to certain file extensions.

As a test I created 2 files with these contents (in essence overriding what I have as default):

```
>  cat Preferences.sublime-settings
{
    "tab_size": 2,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}

>  cat Powershell.sublime-settings 
{
  "tab_size": 12,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}

>  cat Ps1.sublime-settings       
{
  "tab_size": 12,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

I closed and reopened Sublime Text and pressing the tab key still produces 2 spaces for tabs instead of 12.

Any ideas on how to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about the order of precedence but might you have `tab_size` set in your project settings?

Comment: @mattst I highly doubt it as I didn't even know there is a project settings. I just listed all the files in the parent folder and the only thing that I can see there is .git folder and .gitignore.

Comment: The `tab_size` setting will be modified on the fly if `detect_indentation` is set to `true` (which it is by default) and you open a file that detects as having a different tab size. For an apples to apples comparison of settings you need to either turn that off, or test in a brand new blank file. (In addition to what @mattst covered in his answer)

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes you have already installed and been trying to configure the [PowerShell](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PowerShell) package from *Package Control*.

The reason your settings are not working is because the settings' file names that you tried are wrong. The PowerShell package uses the file name `PowershellSyntax.sublime-settings` for its settings, that is what you need to use.

Most packages use their package name as the file name for their `.sublime-settings` file but clearly not all do. In this case there is a much older PowerShell package called [stposh](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/stposh) which already made use of the file name `PowerShell.sublime-settings` so, in all probability, the developer of the newer PowerShell package was forced to choose a different file name to avoid a conflict. Clearly the choice of `PowershellSyntax.sublime-settings` made setting up the package less intuitive, in my opinion the settings file name should be mentioned in the package's README.

```js
// Save as 'PowershellSyntax.sublime-settings'
// in your Sublime Text config 'User' folder.
{
    // 8 or even just 2 is probably better to test with
    // but stick with the massive 12 if you want to. :)
    "tab_size": 12,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

In future if a `.sublime-settings` file does not work, look on the package's homepage which is always linked from *Package Control*. A browse through the source file names will usually quickly reveal the correct settings file name to use. If the package is already installed, you could also open its `.sublime-package` file, which is a `zip` archive, these are stored in the `Installed Packages` folder.

**Some Extra Hints:**

The PowerShell Package should automatically recognise the following file extensions `.ps1, .psm1, .psd1` and use its syntax when they are opened. To force another file extension to automatically use that syntax, e.g. `.ps`, click on the currently active syntax name on the far right of the status bar, a context menu will be shown, hover the mouse pointer over `Open all with current extension as...`, and then select `PowerShell` from the list.

To manually instruct Sublime Text to convert tabs to spaces, or vise versa, click on where it says either `Spaces: n` or `Tab Size: n` on the status bar, doing so will open a context menu. You can then switch between spaces and tab indentation by selecting or unselecting `Indent Using Spaces`. Open the same context menu again and select whichever conversion is then required from the bottom 2 menu items. This last stage can also be performed by typing `indentation` into the *Command Palette* and choosing from the self-explanatory options.

Comment: I don't have any packages installed. Is there a guide for file extensions that don't have packages?

As example. I have .LST files that I want to have its own settings and there's no packages for it.